# Is there an LaTeX editor embeddable in a web site?

Tags: online

For a project I need allow LaTeX input from a from website's users. I want a light weight LaTeX Editor that I can  embed in my website and help them to write and edit their documents.

I want this editor be like LyX - i.e. WYSIWYG(M), tiny and of course open source - if it is possible. If it isn't, I want it to be as easy to use for authors as possible.

Is there any kind of editor like that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try https://www.overleaf.com/

Comment: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/List-of-web-based-math-editors

Comment: I read about overleaf it is very nice and powerful but I want a tiny JS program not  a complete web application

Comment: Hope sharelatex is one of a online tool which meets your requirement...

Comment: @MadyYuvi ShareLaTeX is Overleaf nowadays.

Comment: You could take a look at [JS bin](http://jsbin.com/?html=%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset%3D%22utf-8%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cmeta%20name%3D%22viewport%22%20content%3D%22width%3Ddevice-width%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctitle%3EMathJax%20example%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%3Cscript%20type%3D%22text%2Fjavascript%22%20async%3E%0A%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%0A%20%20amirhosein%20What%20you%20see%20is%20what%20you%20mean%20E=mc%3Csup%3E2%3C%2Fsup%3E%20%5B1%5D%3Cp%3E%5B1%5D%20%26copy%20Einstein%20A%2E%20Go%2DGo%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E&live)

Comment: I don't know that *any* WYSIWYM editor is going to be tiny :-)  What is driving that requirement?

Comment: a editor like a text input box (my mean of tiny ) that user can use it in our site and some button(with that box) that help user write without any knowledge about TeX and send what the user writed for us in TeX format.    we work on a educational site and want user write his  mathematic questions without extra programs and easy. and thank you and excuse me for  bad english